# How to darken a navbar link based on what page you are on?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to have it so that went somebody goes to a certain page of my website the area around the nav-link they clicked darken so they can easily tell what page they are on. I am using Bootstrap v4.3.1 and Razor Pages. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to do it site-wide you can add this to your `_Layout` file and make each nav bar link have an id matching the first path item it takes the user to:

```js
 var x = $(location).attr('pathname'); 
//if the url is:example.com/abc/123?test=100, x is set to /abc/123
 x = x.split("/")[1];
// "/abc/123/" is split up by "/" and x is set to the first item, in this case: "abc"      
 $('#'+x).addClass('onpage');
//finally, it looks for an element with an id of "abc" and adds the class of 'onpage' to it
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help but what I ended up doing is putting the following in the files of each of my pages, except that "Timeline" would be different for each page:
 `<script>
    document.getElementById("Timeline").classList.add("active");
</script>`

Then in my overarching Layout file I changed each file to have a relevant id: 
`<li class="nav-item" id="Timeline">
  <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-page="/Timeline">Timeline</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Add the active class, for example:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the **li** element:

```
<li class="nav-item active">
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the class "active" works but how do I make it so that the active class is only applied to the nav-bar item whose page I am currently on? For example, /Timeline adds the class "active" to my "Timeline" nav-link.

Comment: If your page is static HTML, just add the active class in the menu of the corresponding page.